# Border-Bottom Accordion Panel in different browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery Accordion in which I want to have multiple sections open:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    animate: 500,
  }).on("click", "div", function(e) {
    $("div.ui-accordion-header").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(this).is(".ui-state-active")) {
        $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("-")
      } else {
        $(this).find(".panel-icon").html("+")
      }
    })
  });

});
```

```css
.accordion {
  float: left;
  line-height: 2.0;
  width: 100%;
}
.js_button {
  width: 99%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  outline-width: 0;
}
.panel {
  width: 99%;
  height: 20%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="body">


  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Part1</div>
    <span class="panel">
             <p>Content1</p>
             </span>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="js_button"><span class="panel-icon">+</span>Part2</div>
    <span class="panel">
             <p>Content2</p>
             </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The Accordion itself works fine but when I use **Chrome**, **Safari** or **Opera** I have the following issue with the border-bottom of the panel (content):

When I click on the "button" and the panel slides out the border-bottom is not there. In the end of the slide animation the bordor-bottom is finally drawn.
How can i avoid this and let the border-bottom be there from the beginning of the animation like in Firefox and IE?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Here is also a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/

Comment: I don't really know, but the [examples of jQuery UI itself](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default) seem to show the same behaviour, although it's hard to tell since they are faster and of a lighter color.

Comment: Just updated my answer to make the animation smoother - hope that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the border to the `.accordion` div instead and remove the other borders:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypv8yow1/6/)

```
.accordion {
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.0;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
     margin-top: 1%;
}
.js_button {
    width: 99%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline-width: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.js_button:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
}
.panel {
    width: 99%;
    height: 20%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Noticed that your animation was very jerky - mainly because you are using a span as the panel. Switch this to a div (or set the span to `display:block`) and the animation should be smooth as above.

Also, the `:after` above is for the border-bottom on the button. Adding a standard border-bottom to the button just doubles up the borders, so had to do it this way. Sure there is a better way, but I'll come back when I'm not so tired :)

Comment: Hi wickywills, thank you very much for your answer so far. It works very good. Only in Safari there is still a little bug. Once the panel is slided down you can see that the border-bottom on the button is not ending up with the right-border which causes a very small gap. Besides, I will keep the question open for another 2-3 days so maybe you can send me an even better solution when you not tired anymore ;-) Otherwise I will check the answer arrow :-)

Comment: @Michi Please see updated JSFiddle. Added `box-sizing: border-box` to get around the padding issue on the button. Still can't think of a better way of doing the border on the button with this setup. All depends on how the accordion is designed to look, which would lead to different solutions. This solution should be fine in your case though, and I can't see any other browser issues :)